# How to set Debug/Run config for Tomcat in intelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

Tomcat is installed and working on my Mac OS. This is the folder where I installed the tomcat:

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
```

I know it working alright because typing

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

in browser will open the default tomcat page. But I couldn't set it correctly in IntelliJ running configuration environment.

I chose the correct path for tomcat folder. What is Tomcat Home?

[image]

[image]

Here is the error message:
[image]

I believe I set everything alright, but it just won't work. Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

[Here is the official document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) from IntelliJ on how to set the Run/Debug Config, but it is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should download Tomcat, unpack it in a folder, and then put the folder you unpacked in the "Tomcat Home" and "Tomcat base directory". See if that works out for you.

Found what I'm saying on [this site](https://federicoponte.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/setting-up-tomcat-7-with-intellij-idea/).

Comment: It worked! Thanks! The key point I missed it I don't know Tomcat Home should be the same folder as Tomcat Home. If they should be same, why IntelliJ as me twice?

Comment: There is probably a valid reason for that. Maybe in some cases they should be differently. Home and base directory sound so... similar... has to be a trick question! xD I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Fedora but I the set Tomcat Home setting in IntelliJ to point to the directory where I unpacked Tomcat. In my case Tomcat Home is /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.36

[image: Tomcat Server dialog]

[image: Application Servers in IntelliJ]

Comment: Kinda feel bad with my answer while you took the effort of actually making some screens to give a clear answer. Have an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote. They are always appreciated.